# Grouping by two columns in ag grid pivot mode?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I'm using ag grid in pivot mode :
https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/

Problem that i have is that i have two dimension something like this:

1.Test
 1.1 Test 1
 1.2 Test 2

User can insert for first dimension, or to insert for second dimension where sum of second dimension will have first dimension, and i will save both of dimension. In pivot table i grouping by first and second dimension, but it sum both dimension.

Im getting like this:

[image]

U can see on picture i have empty row where is sum of second dimension. What i want to achive is to remove this empty row, but it display sum depeneds of what dimension is inserted. So if user insert first dimension it will display in first row that value, and in second and third it will be null.

If user insert second dimension it will display in first row summ of that two and in second and third row it will be there values, but no empty row.

In my ts i have this:

```
{
        headerName: 'Channel',
        field: 'incomeChannelName',
        width: 310,
        rowGroup: true,
        enableRowGroup: true
      },


      {
        headerName: 'Category',
        field: 'categoryName',
        width: 310,
        rowGroup: true,
        enableRowGroup: true,
        enablePivot: true
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use row group
{
        headerName: 'Channel',
        field: 'incomeChannelName',
        width: 310,
        enableRowGroup: true
      },

```
  {
    headerName: 'Category',
    field: 'categoryName',
    width: 310,
    enableRowGroup: true,
    enablePivot: true
  },
```

Comment: Hey Guru katwa. While this may solve the problem, you're encouraged to give an explanation *why* that solves the problem